# XSD optional element minOccurs="0" but on validation it is expected?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

My requirement is I have three elements where `ProductID` and `DivisionID` is required and Unit is optional.

### XSD

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="Message">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Product">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="productID">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                              <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                              <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Unit" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                              <xs:minLength value="0"/>
                              <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="DivisionID">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                              <xs:minLength value="0"/>
                              <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message>
   <Product>
      <productID>ABC-EDI</productID>

   </Product>
</Message>
```

### Validation error

> Cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The Content Of Element 'Product' Is Not Complete. One Of '{Unit, DivisionID}' Is Expected., Line '4', Column '14'.

### Question

Error should be that only `DivisionID` is expected.  **Why `Unit` is expected?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XML is valid against your XSD as posted.

If you were to omit the required `DivisionID` element, you would indeed receive an validation error along the lines of

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'Product' is not
>   complete. One of '{Unit, DivisionID}' is expected.

This error should be read as saying not that `Unit` is *required* after `productID` but rather that `Unit` or `DivisionID` is expected to follow `productID`.  You're understandably looking to be told the minimum change necessary to meet the XSD's requirements.  However, it's making a broader statement along the lines of

> ***Hey, I just saw a close tag for `Product`, and its content model
>   remains unsatisfied.  Before `Product` ends, I expected to see one of
>   `Unit` or `DivisionID` at this point.***

Comment: Thanks but why it expects Unit which is not mandatory? Is there a way to simply say what mandatory field is missing? In this case just DivisionID.

Comment: Yes, it ***expects*** next to see `Unit` or `DivisionID` rather than the end tag of `Product`.  ***Expects*** does not mean ***requires***.   No, you cannot change this for any given validating parser.  Yes, you could write your own that could report differently in this case.  No, you would not likely want to take on the computational complexity involved with guaranteeing that your validation violations report the minimum fix required to make the XML valid.